# Dual Boot with Ubuntu as Host?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

Can you dual boot Windows if Ubuntu is already installed? All of the sites I have found only work starting with Windows installed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason most tutorials start with Windows and then install Ubuntu is that Windows installs its own bootloader that does not recognize Ubuntu as a valid OS. Fortunately, it is fairly easy to restore Ubuntu's bootloader, which does recognize Windows.

How I would do this:

1. (before installing Windows) repartition the disk in Ubuntu (Windows needs at least 20 GB)
2. install Windows
3. boot into the Ubuntu LiveCD
4. install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

See this [Ubuntu Documentation article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) for more information.